# Best way to check if a username exists in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm quite new to ruby/rails. I was wondering what is the best way to ensure that two people don't choose the same username. Here is my model at the moment:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :username, :presence => true
   validates :password, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 7}
 end
```

Note: I'm assuming it is best to place this type of code in the model. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a validation to make sure a field is unique. Just change your username validation to:

```
validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also add an index to your usertable, with uniqueness. This way, if people quickly press the username register button twice, you will also be protected at the database level

```
add_index :users, :username, :unique => true
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been correctly answered but for future reference, APIDock has excellent Rails documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails. The search's autocomplete is fantastic.

The documentation for the `validates` method is here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates where you can find the `:uniqueness => true` option.